# Laravel Query for 2 tables Join

Tags: php, ubuntu

When I run any PHP command it gives me this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli'
>   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
>   /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so:
>   undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

Ubuntu 16 os
PHP 7.0 showing in phpinfo
php 7.2 showing in terminal php-v

Comment: Do you have that extension installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, i have installed all the packages , i dont know why its finding it on wrong folder where to change this